# С чего начать изучать Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Сабж (:
Планируется переход с РНР, или не переход, а просто расширение кругозора.
Лучше с самых основ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот подробное руководство](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/ror/138101/).

А если хотете изучить основы  Ruby,тогда [Ссылка 2](http://www.shokhirev.com/mikhail/ruby/ltp/Chapter00.html).

Answer (score 2):

начинать с Ruby

Answer (score 2):

Купил Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)  - вся на scaffold ... просто кошмар, экономят время, а для новичка будет казаться что это волшебная магия.

Лучше начинать с Ruby,  помимо того что порекомендовал diRect_z  стоит посмотреть try roby (Google поможет) и затем пройти Rails for Zombies

Answer (score 0):

С этого: [Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails).

Answer (score 0):

[Гибкая разработка веб-приложений в среде Rails](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/8153111/)